# Почему в JS скрипте вместо кирилицы отображается код символов типа "&#1057;"?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, apache, кодировка, администрирование

Делаю сайт на Wordpress. Сервер - Apache, PHP 7.0.

JS скрипт помещаю в тег  и на сайте кириллица отображается вот так 
"&#1086 ;&#1090 ;&#1087 ;&#1088 ;&#1072" (я поставил пробелы, так как если будет оригинальный код, он конвертируется в текст)

Уже гуглил и искал. Везде прописано utf-8, файл сохранён в  utf-8, обычный текст заключенный в html-теги отображается нормально, а вот именно в скриптах отображается вот так.
файл подключен вот этим кодом
В файле плагина, который с помощью require_once включен в функцию шорткода. Эта функция возвращает контент с помощью ob_get_contents.

```
function wdm_auction_listing($wdm_cat_args=""){
    $auc_sc = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $auc_sc;
}
add_shortcode( 'wdm_auction_listing', 'wdm_auction_listing' );
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А тег у вас где? В записи или на странице?

Comment: В файле плагина, который с помощью require_once включен в функцию шорткода. Эта функция возвращает контент с помощью ob_get_contents.

Comment: Эти символы - это своего рода экранирование.

Comment: Они позволяют выводить на страницу спец.символы как есть.

Comment: Такую подлость Вам делает функция htmlspecialchars, А Вам нужно сделать обратное действие - то есть htmlspecialchars_decode

Comment: Перепутал, смотрите  html_entity_decode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема именно в ob_get_contents(). Ни html_entity_decode, ни htmlspecialchars_decode не помогли.

Проблема в версии php. Стояла php7.0 - кириллица в комментариях и скриптах экранировалась. Поставил 5.6 - всё нормально отображается.

Answer (score 0):

```
function wdm_auction_listing($wdm_cat_args=""){
    $auc_sc = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return html_entity_decode($auc_sc);
}
add_shortcode( 'wdm_auction_listing', 'wdm_auction_listing' );
```

Comment: Такое тоже уже пробовал, попробовал ещё раз - результат тот же.

Comment: Скорее всего Вы JS вносили в режиме html, а нужно source code

Comment: Перепутал, смотрите  html_entity_decode